# Passing data from one frame to other frame in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript

I wrote an action script code for two frames,lets say frame 1 and frame 10. Now onClick() event on frame 1, i wrote like this.

```
 on(release){
gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

Now from frame 1 to frame 10 i want to send some data like a boolean variable. So that i can execute appropriate action in frame 10.

Please let me know the possibilities of passing data between frames.

Comment: static variables. you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeline in Flash is really the top-level `MovieClip` and therefore any properties you set on it are accessible from any frame at that level. I would declare the variable in the first frame on your actions layer (before the `stop()` action I assume you must have) like so:

```
var myBoolean = false; // set default
```

In the action for your button you can set the value of your `boolean`:

```
on(release){
  myBoolean = true; // myBoolean should be in scope from here, if not you could use _root.myBoolean
  gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

And in frame 10 you can create a new frame on your actions layer and write the appropriate logic according to the value of the `boolean`:

```
if (myBoolean) {
 // ...
} else {
 // ...
}
```